# PyOpenGL passing variable to the vertex shader

Tags: python, opengl, glsl, shader, pyopengl

After a few suggestion I decided the learn a little bit OpenGL with the hard way. I tried to pass a **(`float` - named `myAttrib`)** variable to the vertex shader and it seemed to work (line 33), but obviously doesn't. Later I would like to divide the code into further parts.

**Code:**

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import *

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import numpy, time

def getFileContent(file):
    content = open(file, 'r').read()
    return content

def initDraw():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480), HWSURFACE | OPENGL | DOUBLEBUF)

    vertices = [0.0, 0.5,
                0.5, -0.5,
                -0.5, -0.5,]

    vertices = numpy.array(vertices, dtype = numpy.float32)

    myAttrib = 0.3

    vertexShader = compileShader(getFileContent("helloTriangle.vert"), GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    fragmentShader = compileShader(getFileContent("helloTriangle.frag"), GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)

    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram()
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader)
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader)
    glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 1, "myAttrib")
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram)

    print(glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "myAttrib"))

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices)
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)

    pygame.display.flip()
    time.sleep(2)

initDraw()
```

**Vertex shader:**

```
#version 130

attribute vec2 vPosition;
attribute float myAttrib;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(vPosition.x, vPosition.y + myAttrib, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

**Fragment shader:**

```
#version 130

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);            
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use an attribute, the you have to define an array of generic vertex attributes, with one attribute value per vertex coordinate (3 in your case). See [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification).
If you would use a uniform, then you can set one value for the program stored in an uniform variable in the default uniform block (you can imagine this somehow like a global variable). See [Uniform (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)):

**Case 1 - Attribute `myAttrib`:**

*Vertex shader*

```c
#version 130

attribute vec2 vPosition;
attribute float myAttrib;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(vPosition.x, vPosition.y + myAttrib, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

You have to define an array of generic vertex attributes as you do it for the vertex coordinates:

```py
attrib = [-0.2, 0.2, 0.0]
myAttrib  = numpy.array(attrib, dtype = numpy.float32)

# .....

glLinkProgram(shaderProgram)
myAttrib_location = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "myAttrib")

# .....

glVertexAttribPointer(myAttrib_location, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, myAttrib)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(myAttrib_location)
```

or

```py
glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 1, "myAttrib")
glLinkProgram(shaderProgram)

# .....

glVertexAttribPointer(1, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, myAttrib)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)
```

**Case 2 - Uniform `myUniform`**

*Vertex shader*

```c
#version 130

attribute vec2 vPosition;
uniform float myUniform;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(vPosition.x, vPosition.y + myUniform, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Get the location of the uniform (`"myUniform"`) by [`glGetUniformLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetUniformLocation.xhtml) and set the value to the uniform by [`glUniform`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml):

```py
myUniform = 0.3

# .....

glLinkProgram(shaderProgram)
myUniform_location = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "myUniform")

# .....

glUseProgram(shaderProgram)
glUniform1f(myUniform_location, myUniform)

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)
```

Comment: After using the second method which I think fit my need I get this:     glUniform1f(myUniform_location, "myUniform")
  File "latebind.pyx", line 32, in OpenGL_accelerate.latebind.LateBind.__call__ (src/latebind.c:989)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type

Comment: @tenjohn Is not `"myUniform"` it is `myUniform` => `myUniform=0.3` `glUniform1f(myUniform_location, myUniform)` or `glUniform1f(myUniform_location, 0.3)` Note, `glUniform1f` assigns a value (0.3) to the uniform at location `myUniform_location`.